# How to set up task scheduling in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cron, command

I've a website made in Laravel 4.2 and we have a monthly membership with 30 credits. Even if user doesn't use all of them, they should expire at `valid_till` date.

I wish to have a piece of code which will run at 12 am every night and will set credit as 0 in everyone's account who's `valid_till` date is equal to yesterday or before that.

If there could be something like task scheduling in laravel 5.1, which runs a function on particular time of day daily, that would be perfect.
I know cron can be set up in Laravel 4.2, using commands but I'm unable to understand how to use it in my case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a file like the following in app/commands, replace my comment in the fire method with your update function.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class setCreditToZero extends Command {

    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'set:zero';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function fire()
    {
        // your update function here
    }

    /**
     * Get the console command arguments.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getArguments()
    {
        return [

        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the console command options.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return [

        ];
    }

}
```

Register your command in app/start/artisan.php

```
Artisan::add(new setCreditToZero);
```

Now set a cronjob using command on your terminal

```
crontab -e
```

And in this file set a cronjob with this line

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/laravel/baseDir/artisan set:zero
```

And you should be good to go

Comment: Sir I'm unable to find Console folder in Laravel 4. I think it come after Laravel 5. I've put this file in app/commands. I've registered the command in app/start/artisan.php as `Artisan::add(new setCreditToZero);` I've put this cronjob line using command `crontab -e` Just guide me if I've set cronjob correctly. I'm unable to judge if whole system had been set up correctly or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, along with Laravel documentation I'm able to figure out the problem, but your answer is more of Laravel 5 answer.

Comment: No, the command structure is changed in L5, this one should work for 4

Comment: There's nothing like **App\Console** in L5. So registering the command in _Kernel.php_ is not possible in L4, it's done in _artisan.php_ in L4, apart from that **app\commands** is the place where file is stored not **app\console\commands**. Please also mention where to put this cronjob line in your answer, I'm able to figure it out but it took me a couple of more searches for it.

Comment: @baao, which file are you referring to by `And in this file set a cronjob with this line`

Comment: @vijayrana just type crontab -e in your console. A file will open then. See my documentation entry on crontabs for further explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/crontab/5750/getting-started-with-crontab#t=201611281049490397984

Comment: Yes, by typing `crontab -e`, I got a message where I can type. It contains `mailto="mail@myemail.com" and shell="/bin/bash"`. Where is the file located and how to execute the command? could you please explain a bit. :)

Comment: Sure, I already did! See the documentation link I've sent you @vijayrana

Comment: @baao, I think I am getting some point but no luck, I am writing the cron job like this `*/2 * * * * php /home/vijayrana/artisan check:stats`, but I am not getting mails. I have fire method which looks like `public function fire()
 {
  mail('mrner.bijay@gmail.com', 'Cron Job', 'this is a message from cron job');
 }`

Comment: Please ask a new question about it and include the code you're having problems with there @vijayrana